# How to traverse the nodes for a DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am trying to traverse the nodes of the DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList and it isn't working.

Basically all I have is the caption and value of the node I want to look for. Is there a simple way I can find it. After it is found I am just moving the focus to the new node and I already know how to do that if I have the proper index.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a `Queue` and then going through the TreeList using the current node's `tree.nodes`.

```
Dim text As String = "looking for this"
Dim myQueue As New Queue
For i As Integer = 0 To tree.Nodes.Count - 1
    If tree.Nodes(i).GetDisplayText("name").Equals(text ) Then
          tree.SetFocusedNode(tree.Nodes(i))
          Exit Sub
    Else
          If tree.Nodes(i).HasChildren Then
               myQueue.Enqueue(tree.Nodes(i))
          End If
    End If
Next

While myQueue.Count > 0
    Dim tempNode As DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode = CType(myQueue.Dequeue, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode)
    For i As Integer = 0 To tempNode.Nodes.Count - 1
          If tempNode.Nodes(i).GetDisplayText("name").Equals(e.Button.Caption) Then
              tree.SetFocusedNode(tempNode.Nodes(i))
              Exit Sub
          Else
              If tempNode.Nodes(i).HasChildren Then
                   myQueue.Enqueue(tempNode.Nodes(i))
              End If
          End If
    Next
End While
```

Answer (score 1):

Such tasks should be implemented using a node iterator.  Please refer to this [example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E772)

in this regard.  The NodesIterator is described in our documentation:

[NodesIterator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_NodesIteratortopic)